# How to update table to pick up new hdfs paths using presto?

Tags: hdfs, presto

In Hive, I could do `msck repair table tableName;` But if I run the same query in presto I get "no viable alternative at input 'msck'". What does that error message mean and how to get the latest partitions through presto.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `system.sync_partition_metadata` procedure.
https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html?highlight=system.sync_partition_metadata#procedures

Comment: I tried the above solution,`call system.sync_partition_metadata(myschema, table_name, ADD)`, but getting error "Procedure not registered: hive.system.sync_partition_metadata".  Could you share any pointer on how to register the system procedures.

Comment: What Presto version are you using?

Comment: @user1502721 if you run Presto on EMR, make sure to use EMR 6.1 or newer and select "PrestoSQL" component.